# How I wait to an element has some text using protractor?

Tags: typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

How can I do something after my element has a text contaning some words. For example:
I want to do something, after my first td from my table has, as part of it, the text 'Test':

I was thinking using

```
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(element.all(by.tagName('td')).first(), 'Test'), 10000).
```

But this code only get true if the 
text is accurate.

Comment: Would a regular expression match work? If so, try [textMatches](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textMatches-org.openqa.selenium.By-java.util.regex.Pattern-)

Answer (score 0):

Protractor doesn't have a wait function for partial text to be present. However you can make one yourself.

```
browser.wait(function()
{
  return element.all(by.tagName('td')).first().getText().then(function(text)
  {
    return /^Test/.test(text);  //this is a regex test on the element text
  });
},10000);  //timeout time
```

This allows you to use a Regular Expression to check if the text contains 'Test'.